# Angular2 Async Data Issue

Tags: asynchronous, angular

I have a component that is reliant upon an asynchronously fetched object.  There are also child components in the template that rely on some data from this same object.

The problem I am having seems to be a classic race condition, but I'm not familiar enough with Angular 2 to understand the solution.

Take this for instance:

```
export class SampleComponent {
    constructor(service: SomeService) {
        this.service = service;
        this._loadData();
    }

    private _loadData() {
        this.service.getData().subscribe(data => this.data = data);
    }
}
```

But in the template, I have child components to display certain parts of `this.data`:

```
<taglist tags="data?.tags"></taglist>
```

Now the Component for `taglist` looks something like:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'taglist',
    directives: [NgFor],
    inputs: ['tags'],
    template: `<span *ngFor="#tag of tags">{{ tag }}</span>`
})

export class TagList {
    public tags: Array<string> = [];

    constructor() {
        //
    }
}
```

Because tags input is received from an async loaded dataset, its not present when the Tag Component is initialized.  What can I do so that when `this.data` load is finished, the sub components that use it will automatically access the newly loaded data?

**Thank you for any insight you may be able to provide me!**

Answer (score 5):

Implement `ngOnChanges()` (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/OnChanges-interface.html)

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'taglist',
    inputs: ['tags'],
    template: `<span *ngFor="let tag of tags">{{ tag }}</span>`
})

export class TagList {
    public tags: Array<string> = [];

    constructor() {
        //
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: {[propName: string]: SimpleChange}) {
      console.log('ngOnChanges - tags = ' + changes['tags'].currentValue);
    }
}
```

For angular to handle the binding also use

```ts
<taglist [tags]="data?.tags"></taglist> or <taglist tags="{{data?.tags}}"></taglist>
```

otherwise it's a simple string to attribute assignment Angular doesn't handle.

Comment: So I did try this prior,  And when I console.log  chages['tags'].currentValue it prints the string 'data?.tags' instead of the evaluated value :/

Comment: I see. Use `<taglist [tags]="data?.tags"></taglist>` or `<taglist tags="{{data?.tags}}"></taglist>`

Comment: Awesome, I'll try this in a min here. Thanks for the pointers

Answer (score 0):

This is the usual use case for the built-in `async` pipe, that is meant to be used to easily consume observables.

Try the following, first create a getter than returns directly the service layer observable:

```
get data(): Observable {
    return this.service.getData();
}
```

Then you can consume this observable directly in the template using the `async` pipe:

```
<span *ngFor="let tag of data | async">{{ tag }}</span>
```

Comment: Do I need to specify `async` in @Component  `pipes: []` ?